# Using socket.io with ejs on Express/Nginx

Tags: express, nginx, socket.io, ejs

I'm working on a app with socket.io, ejs, express & nginx on a Node JS server.

I have managed to get the socket.io working withthout use of `ejs`.
But when I try to implement it with `ejs` I get `error 400` on `client.js`.
Here is my code for `server.js` :

```
var express     = require('express');
var app         = require('express')();
var server      = require('http').createServer(app);
var io          = require('socket.io')(server);
var ejs         = require('ejs');

// WITHOUT EJS : WORKS FINE
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(index.html');
});

// WITH EJS : GET HTTP ERR 400 IN CLIENT.JS CONSOLE
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.render('pages/index');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('a user connected');
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        console.log('message: ' + msg);
      });
});

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, function(){
    console.log('app running');
});
```

My `nginx` code looks like this :

```
# HTTP — redirect all traffic to HTTPS
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
# HTTPS — proxy all requests to the Node app
server {
    # Enable HTTP/2
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.com;

    # Use the Let’s Encrypt certificates
    ssl_certificate /.../;
    ssl_certificate_key /.../;
    
    location ~* \.io {

      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy false;

      proxy_pass http://example.com:8080;
      proxy_redirect off;

      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

Here is my `client.js` :

```
var socket = io(); 
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
});
```

What could be the issue here ?

Comment: There was an issue with socket.io library on the client side. I used latest version of socket.io <script src = "/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script> which fixed the issue.